# Is it grammatically correct to say, "A figure yonders"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Firstly, I wanted to know if it is acceptable to use the word *yonders*? Originally I wanted to use it to indicate something at a far distance ("A figure yonders") but later on, I realised that I should have probably used *yonder* instead of *yonders*. This happened while writing a poem that I published last year. It is just one line- "A figure yonders". Even then, in a vague sense, is it grammatically right to say "A figure yonders"?

Comment: Yonders is not a verb.  Just as “over theres” is not a verb.

Comment: Yon and yonder are (were) demonstratives of direction, not distance. "Through yon window you can see the river." indicates which window, not that the window, or the river, is far away. It is usually used to indicate a landmark on which to line ones sights. The target is often beyond the landmark, but not necessarily so. The target can be towards yon mountains, indicating you will get there before you get to the mountains.

Answer (score 3):

In a poem, it's perfectly alright. *Yonder* as a word is dated, but not archaic. *Yonder**s*** on the other hand is not listed in modern dictionaries, although it does seem to have been a variant of *yonder*:

Seven and a Half years in the Far West (1843):

*he made **yonders** sun -- and **yonders** moon -- and all them' are stars what shines at night*

The Italian Husband (1698)

*drag him along to **yonders** wheel, there he shall endless tortures feel*

Comment: Well spotted, those examples. +1

Comment: Do you think that, originally, it might have been a possessive as in "the moon, sun and wheel _belonging to_ or _existing in_ the far distance"?